# Keeping ignored folder/files with "git clean -fdx"

Tags: git

We have github repo that grows big so I had to zip and move shared packages to LFS. When I checkout repo, I run a script that extracts ZIPs to separate folders in the project. 
So I have `repo/lfs/packages/*.zip` (in LFS) and they are extracted to `/repo/packages/package-name/*` (not tracked, placed in .gitignore)

`repo/packages/` folder is added to .gitignore, folder structure is the same and everything works fine.

On a build machine however, build agent runs `git cleanup -f -d -x` so `repo/packages/` folder is deleted. I have to unzip packages again and it takes a lot of time and resources. Unfortunately I can't change cleanup command.

Is it possible to prevent ignored folders from cleanup? Ideally I'd like to keep packages folder in the same place. Thanks!

Comment: You need to remove the `-x` option to NOT delete ignored files. — However, aren't the packages versioned as well? If not, why to store them in Git? (or GitLFS) – If they are, how do you keep track of package changes? Git can't `diff` them from inside a zip file. – However, **git ops are to init code** (e.g. cleanall); the build should be agnostic of `git` ops. Supposedly the build agent calls a `make build` from your repo code: your unzip-script should run inside there — I feel like you have to talk with the (grumpy) guy that maintains the build CI; he's the one that can solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

`git clean` preserves ignored files by default, the `-x` option tells it to delete them instead. So to keep your ignored files safe, you need to remove the `-x` option.

Answer (score 1):

Make your /repo/packages/package-name/ a git reposotiry. git clean would never recurse into another repository

Comment: A bit drastic as a solution! 

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's some conceptual mistake. What do you need the `git clean` operation for? Just to cleanup eventual mess?
Is this to keep clean a *stage* or *production* system?

I believe you are doing

- git checkout v1.0.0
- unzip checked out files
- git cleanall (for safety?)
- make build

<sup>(the issue here is to alternate Git commands with Build commands)</sup>

but probably you should be doing a clean **before** the checkout, and for sure **before** the unzip-script is run.

- git cleanall (for safety?)
- git checkout v1.0.0
- make

  - unzip checked out files
  - compile code to build

Try to keep Git commands aggregated as first filesystem-operations (e.g. refactor them in a `bin/gitsetup <commit-name>` script.
*Then* run your code/app operations, from a `Makefile` (or other) script.

Keep concerns separated and you will probably not incur in problems like you are having.